# Unity 3d and Firebase // Open google play when user click on notification

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-cloud-messaging

I started using Google Firebase and I'm learning how to use it. It is a really nice platform, but it's lacked documentation for Unity development. I'm stuck with the very simple task.

I'm sending messages from console to users on mobile with no problem. But when I tried to add a feature to open Google-Play, for example, I don't know how to do it. In firebase console, there is an option to add custom data, but I don't know how to retrieve it in a c# script. Below is a script, that is not working.

```
public void OnMessageReceived(object sender, Firebase.Messaging.MessageReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Received a new message from: " + e.Message.From);       

    UnityEngine.Debug.Log("Received a new message from: " + e.Message.Notification.ClickAction);

    var notification = e.Message.Notification;
    if (e.Message.Notification.ClickAction !=null)
    {
        Application.OpenURL("market://details?q=pname:com.Kruhoborc.Seety/");
    }

}
```

Does somebody know how to add a feature on notifications to open applications?

Comment: I hope it is true. Can you show me the original answer? Thank you.

Comment: It's not a duplicate. Your suggestion talks only about opening an app. My problem is that I don't know how to get that when a user clicks on the notification.

Comment: Use "@user" to reply to people when they close your question. Otherwise, they won't see your comment and it will look like they are ignoring you. Fix your question about where you are stuck and what's happening at this time. I will be willing to open it.